# Connecting atmega328 to 9v battery

Tags: resistors

I'm trying to connect atmega328P-PU micro-controller to a 9v battery. I added 20M ohm resistor and got the voltage down to 4.8v, which is in the range of atmega, but it doesn't turn on. I replaced the atmega with LED and the LED is very dim, even though I'm getting 4.8v. When I try to measure current, I guess it's too weak and the LED doesn't glow at all.

As far a I understood, the resistor is stripping down current as well. Why is this happening? How can I keep the original current potential and reduce only the voltage?

Comment: quick calculation: U = R*i, 9V = 20M * i, so i = 450nA short circuit current max - so, even if it were a good idea to use resistors as a voltage regulator, your value is way off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your atmega is an active load (a variable resistor), lets say it draws (since I don't know but you can run through the caluclations again if you measure it) 20mA then at 5V its like a 250Ohm resistor.

$$ V = I*R  $$

What if it draws 40mA when more transistors turn on? Then its like a 125Ohm resistor.  If you put a 20MOhm resistor in series with a 250 Ohm resistor then your total resistance in the circuit is 20M+250 or 2000250Ohms. The total current through both resistors would be 0.002mA or 2uA. The voltage that your atmega will see will will be I*R = V or (2uA*250= ~4uV) That isn't enough voltage for it to function. Resistors do a lousy job of regulation. So you need a way to regulate the voltage like a 7805 (5V) regulator. They also make DC to DC converters that are also compatible and there are countless circuits available on the internet if you have reasonable searching skills.

Answer (score 1):

Use a suitable voltage regulator, such as an LM7805.

Comment: So I can't simply use the resistors to knock the voltage down and keep the current potential?

Comment: Of course you can't!

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. I misunderstood how resistors work.

Comment: quick question, can I use 2N3904 instead of LM7805?

Comment: Not without several additional components, such as a zener diode.

Comment: A 2N3904 is an NPN transistor, and an LM7805 is an integrated circuit voltage regulator - not the same thing at all, and not interchangeable.  You could build a voltage regulator using the 2N3904, and several other components.

Comment: That is what I said!